# Intellij will not start with the error: "Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main"

Tags: intellij-idea

I killed an "idea" process in terminal after Intellij had frozen. The idea.sh script was missing after I killed the process (I ran a find command and checked other directories & the trash but no luck). I have since copied my friends "idea.sh" script into its former location. Now when I run ./idea.sh I get:

> "Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main".

I have tried searching for this class as well but got no results. Google has no info and I'm not very informed on Intellij.

Any hints on what I might need to do to avoid reinstalling Intellij?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Was your copy installed via toolbox, or via a direct install?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu, although i think its a modified version used in a company. See below output of uname command. Linux vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 3.13.0-79-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 14:27:58 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: It was installed as part of the ubuntu image. We have installed it on virtualbox. a reinstall would require importing a lot of projects & setup but not impossible but I was hoping there might be something quick that i missed or a command i could run.

Comment: Re-download from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download or https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html and install to a new empty directory.

Comment: just done and it picked up all my projects and settings! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after updating the android studio. I was not able to launch it from click on Android Studio icon and after running `./studio.sh` it was giving me the same error

I do this to solve my issue

```
I downloaded the studio and install it in the new directory. 

After installation success, copy all the files & folders and paste and replace it into the old location where the studio was installed. 

And it is working fine.
```